# node js check if data exists in mysql table.- TypeError: res.send is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, node.js

I am trying to check if data exists in mysql table. I get an error **TypeError: res.send is not a function**.

My mysql table has a lot of data but 3 columns with all varchar(45) and id (autoincremental) which is -

```
**id | metrics | custom_metrics**
  1  | test    | test
```

my **js** file inside routes -

```
    router.post('/addcustom',function(req,res){
        try {
            /*if (req.body != null) {*/
                var customMetric = req.body.customMetric;
                //var metrics = req.body.metrics;
                var comma = ',';
                console.log("***CUSTOMMETRIC1: "+JSON.stringify(customMetric) +"comma: "+comma);
                // check if data exists in table start
                connection.query('select custom_metrics from metrics_list where custom_metrics = ?',[customMetric], function(err, result, response) {
                     if (err) {
                        console.log('Count Error :' + err);
                    } else {
                        console.log("METRICS WHERE FOUND: "+JSON.stringify(result)+"****req.body.customMetric== "+customMetric);
                        var res = JSON.stringify(result);

                        if(result!=''||result!=null){

                           res.send('yes');

                           return false;

                        } else {
                            console.log("NOT FOUND");
                        }
                    }
                }); //select custom metrics validation check query

            //check if data exists in table end
            /*connection.query('INSERT INTO metrics_list (customMetric,metrics) values ("' + customMetric + '"' +comma +'"' + metrics +'")', function(err, result) {*/
                connection.query('SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT custom_metrics) FROM metrics_list;', function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Count Error :' + err);
                } else {
                    console.log('Metrics Successfully Counted:' + JSON.stringify(result));
                   // console.log("CUSTOMMETRIC HTML req: "+customMetric);
             // connection query nesting 1start
                   var id1 = JSON.stringify(result).replace(/\D/g,'');
                   console.log("ID1: "+id1);
                    connection.query('UPDATE metrics_list SET custom_metrics = ? WHERE id = ?', [customMetric,id1], function(err, result1) {
                    if (err) {
                      console.log('Count Error :' + err);
                    } else {
                       console.log(" Update Successfully "+JSON.stringify(result1));
                      //res.redirect('/metrics/add');
                   }
                    });

                }
            });
        /*}*/
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log("Exception : " + ex);
    } 
})
```

My ajax call in the html page is-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#addbtn').on('click',function(){
            var customMetric = $('#cus_metrics').val();
            var dataString = 'customMetric='+customMetric;
            //alert(dataString);
            var letterNumber = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/; 
            if(customMetric =='') {        
             alert("This field cannot be empty");
            }// if null ends
            else if(customMetric.length <= 3 || customMetric.length >= 20){
                alert("This field must contain atleaset more than 3 and less than 20 characters");
                return false;
            }
            else {
            $.ajax({
                method:'POST',
                url:'/metrics/addcustom',
                data:dataString,
                success:function(response){     
                if (response == 'no') {
                            //alert("success");
                           /* $("#success-alert").css("display", "block");
                            top.location.href = "/dashboard";*/
                            alert("GOT A NO");
                        }             
                        else{
                            alert("got a yes");
                        }    

                }
            }); //$.ajax ends
}
        });
</script>
```

My HTML button points to the js file, I am only adding the button html since I need help only for the ajax part and the save and list works perfectly

```
<div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Add New Custom Metrics</label>
                                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                                            <input type="text" id="cus_metrics" name="cus_metrics" class="form-control" placeholder="" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                                <div style="text-align: left;width:100%;height:100%;">
                                    <button type="button" id="addbtn" style="margin-left: 28%;width: 28%;" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                                </div>                                            
                                        </div>                                        
                                </div>
```

According to my ajax code , I am sending parameters ID to the JS file and as the query suggests, I am trying to use a where clause `connection.query('select custom_metrics from metrics_list where custom_metrics = ?',[customMetric], function(err, result, response)`.

I want to send a response to the HTML file, and get a POP up alert box if the file exists using the res.send method, which apparently is not working. Request you to help me with the perfect code since I am stuck with this for a day now!!

HELP is appreciated...

Comment: `var res = JSON.stringify(result);` that's why it's not a function

Comment: ohhh woow thanks.. that worked !! That was a quick reply... CHEERS buddy.. I have made a change in my code, and now it works perfectly..

Answer (score 0):

my server side js code with a small modification which is working 100% is as follows -

```
router.post('/addcustom',function(req,res){
    try {
        /*if (req.body != null) {*/
            var customMetric = req.body.customMetric;
            //var metrics = req.body.metrics;
            var comma = ',';
            console.log("***CUSTOMMETRIC1: "+JSON.stringify(customMetric) +"comma: "+comma);
            // check if data exists in table start
            connection.query('select custom_metrics from metrics_list where custom_metrics = ?',[customMetric], function(err, result, response) {
                 if (err) {
                    console.log('Count Error :' + err);
                } else {
                    console.log("METRICS WHERE FOUND: "+JSON.stringify(result)+"ONLY RESULT :"+result+"****req.body.customMetric== "+customMetric);
                    //var res = JSON.stringify(result);
                    console.log("RESULTS LENGTH: "+result.length);
                    if(result.length > 0){                        

                       console.log("*****FOUND****");
                       res.send('yes'); 
                          return false;

                    } else {

                        console.log("NOT FOUND");

          // ********************************************
                       connection.query('SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT custom_metrics) FROM metrics_list;', function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Count Error :' + err);
                } else {
                    console.log('Metrics Successfully Counted:' + JSON.stringify(result));
                   // console.log("CUSTOMMETRIC HTML req: "+customMetric);
             // connection query nesting 1start
                   var id1 = JSON.stringify(result).replace(/\D/g,'');
                   console.log("ID1: "+id1);
                    connection.query('UPDATE metrics_list SET custom_metrics = ? WHERE id = ?', [customMetric,id1], function(err, result1) {
                    if (err) {
                      console.log('Count Error :' + err);
                    } else {
                       console.log(" Update Successfully "+JSON.stringify(result1));
                      //res.redirect('/metrics/add');
                   }
                    });

                }
            }); // select distinct close

        //********************************************


                    }// else result null
                } // conn query check to validate
            }); //select custom metrics validation check query 

            //check if data exists in table end
            /*connection.query('INSERT INTO metrics_list (customMetric,metrics) values ("' + customMetric + '"' +comma +'"' + metrics +'")', function(err, result) {*/


        /*}*/
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log("Exception : " + ex);
    }
})
```

And My Ajax is -

```
   script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#addbtn').on('click',function(){
            var customMetric = $('#cus_metrics').val();
            var dataString = 'customMetric='+customMetric;
            //alert(dataString);
            var letterNumber = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/; 
            if(customMetric =='') {        
             alert("This field cannot be empty");
            }// if null ends
            else if(customMetric.length <= 3 || customMetric.length >= 20){
                alert("This field must contain atleaset more than 3 and less than 20 characters");
                return false;
            }
            else {
            $.ajax({
                method:'POST',
                url:'/metrics/addcustom',
                data:dataString,
                success:function(response){     
                if (response == 'yes') {
                            //alert("success");
                           /* $("#success-alert").css("display", "block");
                            top.location.href = "/dashboard";*/
                            alert("GOT A yes");
                            return false;
                        }   else {
                            return true;
                        }  

                }
            }); //$.ajax ends
}
        });
</script>
```